# How to access 'this' from an object with in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, bind

I have a js object like this:

```
let service = function () {
  this.a = 100;
}

service.prototype.func = function() {
  console.log(this.a)
}

service.prototype.func2 = function () {
  console.log('func2')
  this.func();
}

service.prototype.obj = {
  m: {
    n: {
      o: function() {
        this.func2();
      },
      p: service.prototype.func2.bind(service.prototype)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access the 'a' from o or p, here's the code:

```
let s = new service();
console.log(s.a)
s.func()
s.func2()
s.obj.m.n.p()
s.obj.m.n.o()
```

and the output is

```
100
100
func2
100
func2
undefined
test.js:20
        this.func2();
             ^

TypeError: this.func2 is not a function
```

Any idea that how I can write o/p properly to perform like func2?

Comment: s.obj.m.n.o.call(s) should work. I dont think you can do much with s.obj.m.n.p() as p is returning a function where this is hard bound.

Comment: Javascript objects have no concept of a parent object so you can't get access to that from within a child unless you specifically store a parent reference in your own property.  This is partially because a child object only exists as a reference in a parent property and it could be referenced in many objects.  In other words, a child isn't actually owned by any specific parent.  It's just a reference in a property and could be a reference in many different objects.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
var service = function() {
    this_ = this;
    this.a = 100;
}

service.prototype.func = function() {
    console.log(this.a)
}

service.prototype.func2 = function() {
    console.log('func2')
    this.func();
}

service.prototype.obj = {
    m: {
        n: {
            o: function() {
                this_.func2();
            },
            p: service.prototype.func2.bind(service.prototype)
        }
    }
}

var s = new service();
console.log(s.a)
s.func()
s.func2()
s.obj.m.n.p()
s.obj.m.n.o()
```

UPDATE:

As pointed out by Jaromanda X, I'm updating the code to do what the OP wanted without defining the global variable (I forgot about that).

```
var service = function(v) {
    this.a = v;
    this.obj = this.objFunc(this);
}

service.prototype.func = function() {
    console.log(this.a)
}

service.prototype.func2 = function() {
    console.log('func2')
    this.func();
}

service.prototype.objFunc = function(self) {
    return {
        m: {
            n: {
                o: function() {
                    self.func2();
                },
                p: service.prototype.func2.bind(service.prototype)
            }
        }
    };
}


var s = new service(100);
var s2 = new service(200);

s.func();
s2.func();

s.obj.m.n.o());
s2.obj.m.n.o());
```

The difference between this code and the OP's code is that obj is a property of the each service instance while the OP's code sets the obj as a generic property to the service class.

Also, I set the obj property to call the objFunc class so he can access it as s.obj.m.n.o().  If I didn't he would have to access it as s.obj().m.n.o().

I hope this is what he had in mind and wanted.

Comment: `this_` is a global variable - create a second new service and `s.obj.m.n.o()` will not work as you may expect. Also, this does not address the issue with `s.obj.m.n.p()`

Comment: @Jaromanda - I wasn't aware that this_ is a global variable, do you have a url that I can read up on this?  Thanks

Comment: can you see `this_` declared as `var this_` in a non global scope? Neither can I - there's nothing special about the name `this_` - it's just how you are (not) declaring it that makes it global - You don't need me to send you a link - it's javascript 101

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the code to support obj property for each instance of the service class.